# Wordpress front end not displayed correctly

Tags: wordpress

I have just loaded Wordpress locally and all is fine other than the the front end does not display correctly, with the main menu items shown vertically. (I have tried to upload a picture of the problem but I am not sure if it is even being displayed - an alternative view is [here](http://www.i-observe.co.uk/uploads/WordpressScreen.png))

[image]

Comment: ON debugger mode of wordpress and check might be there php error ( so footer js is properly loaded )

Comment: Thanks - I have tried debug mode but that does not display either. Assuming footer is not loading what do I need to do to get it to? I have seen that this is a likely problem.

Comment: Actually the more I look at this I can't do much - quick edit is not working at all for example.